# Angular 2 rxJs, subscribe error

Tags: http, rxjs, angular2-services

I have method in some service:

```
public approveTokenExpiration(): Observable<any> {
    let header = new Headers();
    header.append('Authorization', this.getTokenHeaderValue());
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: header});
    return this.http.get(Constants.oauthLoginEndPointUrl, options)
      .map(res => {
        return res;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        return refreshToken()
          .subscribe(res => {
            return res;
          });
      });
  }
```

refresh token method:

```
public refreshToken(): Observable<any> {
    let refreshToken = localStorage.getItem(Constants.REFRESH_TOKEN);
    let refreshEndPointUrl = Constants.oauthLoginEndPointUrl + "?grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=" +
      Constants.clientId + "&client_secret=" + Constants.clientSecret + "&refresh_token=" + refreshToken;
    this.http
      .post(refreshEndPointUrl, {})
      .map(res => {
        this.setAuthLocalStorageItems(res);
        this.removeAuthLocalStorageItems();
        return res;
      });
  }
```

And subscription:

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this.customOptions = options;
    return this.authService.approveTokenExpiration()
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          this.addAuthHeader();
          return super.request(url, this.customOptions);
        },
        err => {
          this.authService.refreshToken();
          this.addAuthHeader();
          return super.request(url, this.customOptions);
        });
  }
```

I'm getting following error:

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/app/auth/intercept/auth.interceptor.ts:18:5 
>       TS2322: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.
>     Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

And check pls if everything is okay with my RxJs handling;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code. The specific problem you raised is caused by this part:

```
request(url: string|Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    this.customOptions = options;
    return this.authService.approveTokenExpiration()
      .subscribe(... // <- this will return a Subscription
```

Notice that you define the `request` function to return a result of type `Observable<Response>`.  However, your return statement is returning `...subscribe()`, which is a `Subscription`.  If you want to return an observable, don't call `.subscribe()`. Just return what you get from `approveTokenExpiration()`

You're on the right track. The `request` function should return an `Observable`.  It is the calling code (your component) that should call `.subscribe()` on that Observable because it is at that point the request will be triggered.